# I am unable to Find Configurable options on Product page Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magiczoomplus

I have customized pages in magento, it was working fine until I installed Extension MagiczoomPlus. Now When I create a Configurable Product as shown in [this link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product). I am unable to find my Configuration options on product detail page. even the add to cart button is not visible. I tried to look with developers View but Conldn't find configration.phtml loaded on product page. Please help How to resolve this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/magiczoomplus/media.phtml

or in the folder that it is in you will find other bits of code that magiczoom adds. I don't know what you have altered but if you have been altering the products page it may be worth checking out. Also if you have been adding any other javascripts, I would check that you have got jquery no conflict setup in the right place.